# Unreasonable errors in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
 var buggy_brand_name = ['Baby Jogger', 'Babyzen', 'Bugaboo', 'GB', 'Icandy', 'Joie', 'Maclaren', 'Mamas&Papas', 'Maxi cosi', 'Mountain Buggy', "Out 'N' About", 'Phil and Teds',
'Quinny', 'Silver Cross', 'Stokke', 'UppaBaby'];
var multi_model = [['City Elite', 'City Lite', 'City Mini', 'City Mini GT', 'City Mini ZIP', 'City Select', 'City Versa GT', 'City Vue', 'Summit X3'],
  ['Yoyo+', 'Zen'],
  ['Buffalo', 'Cameleon3', 'Bee +', 'Bee 3', 'Bee 5', 'Donkey'],
  ['Pockit'],
  ['Peach Pushchair', 'Peach Pushchair and Carrycot', 'Peach All Teraine Pushchair and Carrycot', 'Peach All Teraine Pushchair', 'Apple Pushchair',
  'Apple 2 Pear Pushchair (Double)', 'Strawberry Pushchair', 'Strawberry Style Collection Pushchair', 'Strawberry 2 Pushchair'],
  ['Nitro'],
  ['Techno XLR', 'Techno XT', 'Quest', 'Triumph'],
  ['Armadillo', 'Voyage', 'Zoom', 'Ocarro'],
  ['Elea', 'Mura', 'Stella', 'Nova', 'Dana'],
  ['Nano', 'Urban', 'Terrain', 'Duet', 'Swift', 'Mini'],
  ['Nipper', 'Sport Nipper', 'Nipper Double', 'Nipper 360'],
  ['Dot', 'Smart', 'Sport ', 'Dash', 'Mod', 'Voyager', 'Lux', 'Verve'],
  ['Moodd', 'Buzz', 'Zapp'],
  ['Pioneer', 'Wayfarer ', 'Zest', 'Pop', 'Reflex'],
  ['Xplory', 'Scoot', 'Trailz'],
  ['Cruz 2017', 'UppaBaby Vista', 'UppaBaby G-Luxe']];
for(var i = 0; i < buggy_brand_name.length;  i++) {
$('#brand').append('<option value="' + buggy_brand_name[i] + '">' + buggy_brand_name[i] + '</option>');

$('#brand').on('change', function() {
$('#model_fieldset').css({display: 'block'});
  var brand = $('#brand').val();
  var model = $('#model');
  switch (brand)
  {
    case 'Baby Jogger':
      $('.sell-model').remove();
      for (var i = 0; i < multi_model[0][i].length; i++) {
        model.append('<option class="sell-model" value="' + multi_model[0][i] + '">' +multi_model[0][i] + '</option>');
      }
      break;
    case 'Babyzen':
      $('.sell-model').remove();
      for (var i = 0; i < multi_model[1][i].length; i++) {
        model.append('<option class="sell-model" value="' + multi_model[1][i] + '">' +multi_model[1][i] + '</option>');
      }
      break;
    case 'Bugaboo':
      $('.sell-model').remove();
      for (var i = 0; i < multi_model[2][i].length; i++) {
        model.append('<option class="sell-model" value="' + multi_model[2][i] + '">' +multi_model[2][i] + '</option>');
      }
      break;
    case 'GB':
      $('.sell-model').remove();
      for (var i = 0; i < multi_model[3][i].length; i++) {
        model.append('<option class="sell-model" value="' + multi_model[3][i] + '">' +multi_model[3][i] + '</option>');
      }
      break;
    case 'Icandy':
      $('.sell-model').remove();
      for (var i = 0; i < multi_model[4][i].length; i++) {
        model.append('<option class="sell-model" value="' + multi_model[4][i] + '">' +multi_model[4][i] + '</option>');
      }
      break;
    case 'Joie':
      $('.sell-model').remove();
      for (var i = 0; i < multi_model[5][i].length; i++) {
        model.append('<option class="sell-model" value="' + multi_model[5][i] + '">' +multi_model[5][i] + '</option>');
      }
      break;
    case 'Maclaren':
      $('.sell-model').remove();
      for (var i = 0; i < multi_model[6][i].length; i++) {
        model.append('<option class="sell-model" value="' + multi_model[6][i] + '">' +multi_model[6][i] + '</option>');
      }
      break;
    case 'Mamas&Papas':
      $('.sell-model').remove();
      for (var i = 0; i < multi_model[7][i].length; i++) {
        model.append('<option class="sell-model" value="' + multi_model[7][i] + '">' +multi_model[7][i] + '</option>');
      }
      break;
    case 'Maxi cosi':
      $('.sell-model').remove();
      for (var i = 0; i < multi_model[8][i].length; i++) {
        model.append('<option class="sell-model" value="' + multi_model[8][i] + '">' +multi_model[8][i] + '</option>');
      }
      break;
    case 'Mountain Buggy':
      $('.sell-model').remove();
      for (var i = 0; i < multi_model[9][i].length; i++) {
        model.append('<option class="sell-model" value="' + multi_model[9][i] + '">' +multi_model[9][i] + '</option>');
      }
      break;
    case "Out 'N' About":
      $('.sell-model').remove();
      for (var i = 0; i < multi_model[10][i].length; i++) {
        model.append('<option class="sell-model" value="' + multi_model[10][i] + '">' +multi_model[10][i] + '</option>');
      }
      break;
    case 'Phil and Teds':
      $('.sell-model').remove();
      for (var i = 0; i < multi_model[11][i].length; i++) {
        model.append('<option class="sell-model" value="' + multi_model[11][i] + '">' +multi_model[11][i] + '</option>');
      }
      break;
    case 'Quinny':
      $('.sell-model').remove();
      for (var i = 0; i < multi_model[12][i].length; i++) {
        model.append('<option class="sell-model" value="' + multi_model[12][i] + '">' +multi_model[12][i] + '</option>');
      }
      break;
    case 'Silver Cross':
      $('.sell-model').remove();
      for (var i = 0; i < multi_model[13][i].length; i++) {
        model.append('<option class="sell-model" value="' + multi_model[13][i] + '">' +multi_model[13][i] + '</option>');
      }
      break;
    case 'Stokke':
      $('.sell-model').remove();
      for (var i = 0; i < multi_model[14][i].length; i++) {
        model.append('<option class="sell-model" value="' + multi_model[14][i] + '">' +multi_model[14][i] + '</option>');
      }
      break;
    case 'UppaBaby':
      $('.sell-model').remove();
      for (var i = 0; i < multi_model[15][i].length; i++) {
        model.append('<option class="sell-model" value="' + multi_model[15][i] + '">' +multi_model[15][i] + '</option>');
      }
      break;
  };
```

Everything is working but I get these errors:

> sybg_js_1.js:75 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>   at HTMLSelectElement. (sybg_js_1.js:75)
>   at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>   at HTMLSelectElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>
> (anonymous) @ sybg_js_1.js:75
>   dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>   q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>
> sybg_js_1.js:81 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>
> at HTMLSelectElement. (sybg_js_1.js:81)
>   at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       (anonymous) @ sybg_js_1.js:81
>       dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       sybg_js_1.js:99 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of 
>       ndefined
>       at HTMLSelectElement. (sybg_js_1.js:99)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       (anonymous) @ sybg_js_1.js:99
>       dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       sybg_js_1.js:105 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of 
>       undefined
>       at HTMLSelectElement. (sybg_js_1.js:105)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       (anonymous) @ sybg_js_1.js:105
>       dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       sybg_js_1.js:147 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of 
>       undefined
>       at HTMLSelectElement. (sybg_js_1.js:147)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       (anonymous) @ sybg_js_1.js:147
>       dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       sybg_js_1.js:75 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of 
>       undefined
>       at HTMLSelectElement. (sybg_js_1.js:75)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       (anonymous) @ sybg_js_1.js:75
>       dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       sybg_js_1.js:81 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of 
>       undefined
>       at HTMLSelectElement. (sybg_js_1.js:81)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       (anonymous) @ sybg_js_1.js:81
>       dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       sybg_js_1.js:87 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of 
>       undefined
>       at HTMLSelectElement. (sybg_js_1.js:87)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       (anonymous) @ sybg_js_1.js:87
>       dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       sybg_js_1.js:93 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of 
>       undefined
>       at HTMLSelectElement. (sybg_js_1.js:93)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       (anonymous) @ sybg_js_1.js:93
>       dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       sybg_js_1.js:99 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of 
>       undefined
>       at HTMLSelectElement. (sybg_js_1.js:99)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       (anonymous) @ sybg_js_1.js:99
>       dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       sybg_js_1.js:105 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of 
>       undefined
>       at HTMLSelectElement. (sybg_js_1.js:105)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       (anonymous) @ sybg_js_1.js:105
>       dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       sybg_js_1.js:111 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of 
>       undefined
>       at HTMLSelectElement. (sybg_js_1.js:111)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       (anonymous) @ sybg_js_1.js:111
>       dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       sybg_js_1.js:117 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of 
>       undefined
>       at HTMLSelectElement. (sybg_js_1.js:117)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       (anonymous) @ sybg_js_1.js:117
>       dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       sybg_js_1.js:165 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of 
>       undefined
>       at HTMLSelectElement. (sybg_js_1.js:165)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
>       (anonymous) @ sybg_js_1.js:165
>       dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
>       q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3

Does any one know why?

Comment: The most unreasonable part of the code is the lack of code reuse.

Comment: Did you try length() in place of length ?

Comment: .lenght is not a function

Comment: Master Yoda. Do you have any sugdestions? I didn't quite understand your coment.

Comment: marking down for spelling errors, poor attempt to troubleshoot yourself and because there is so much pointless repetitive code, try using calling the same function, a function your create, for each case statement this will allow you to troubleshoot your issue better

Answer (score 0):

In all your cases you want to exchange `multi_model[10][i].length` with `multi_model[10].length` (with the respective index instead of 10).

For your loop condition you need the length of a certain element in `multi_model`. While `multi_model`s elements are arrays themselves, they do not contain any more arrays but rather strings.

Especially the condition `i < multi_model[0][i].length` should have made you wonder, that something isn't logical here.

Good luck!